# How do i fix this Mongo Route so it adds to the friends array?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, postman

Im trying to add a route that allows a user to add another user and be moved into the friends array. For some reason, this route isnt working. Im not getting errors in my terminal or in post man.

```
router.post('/user/:id/friend/:id', async function (req, res) {
  const friend = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.userId, { $addToSet: { friends: req.params.friendId } })
  const friend2 = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.friendId, { $addToSet: { friends: req.params.userId } })
  res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

Also, below is my user model

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')

const User = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      validator: function (v) {
        return /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v)
      },
      message: 'Please enter a valid email'
    },
    required: [true, 'Email required']
  },
  thoughts: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'thought'
  }],
  friends: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'user'
    }
  ]

},

{
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
  },
  id: false
})

User.virtual('friendCount').get(function () {
  return this.friends.length
})

module.exports = model('user', User)
```

Comment: You can try to see (e.g. `console.log`) what those `findByIdAndUpdate` actually return. Also, please remove the "java" tag from your question. It's all JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: If you want to use `req.params.userId` doesn't the route need to use `:userId` instead of `:id`?

Comment: hello, thanks for the help! Sorry pretty new here. @Joe that worked!